# python: get the abstract syntax tree of imported function?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I've already imported a python module in the interpreter. How can I get the abstract syntax tree of the imported module (and any functions and classes within it) within the interpreter? I don't want to have to re-parse the source files. Thanks!

Comment: "I don't want to have to re-parse the source files."  Why not?  That's a pretty silly restriction.  Is there a reason?

Comment: it's inefficient, seems like there should be a way to do so with the already-loaded module.

Comment: I don't think you can get an AST without re-parsing.  I believe Python parses the file, converts it to bytecode, and then throws away the AST, all at import time.  In fact, if a pyc or pyo file is present, it may never build an AST at all, instead directly loading bytecode.  I bet you can find and disassemble the Python bytecode if you want, but that's probably less helpful.

Comment: "it's inefficient"?  Really?  The cost is microscopic and almost unmeasurable.  What are you doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you find some inspiration in this recipe:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/533146-ast-pretty-printer/

> A function that outputs a human-readable version of a Python AST.

Python 2 option (as [compiler is removed in Python 3](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/compiler.html#module-compiler)): Use `compiler` combined with `inspect` (which, of course, still uses the source):

```
>>> import compiler, inspect
>>> import re # for testing 
>>> compiler.parse(inspect.getsource(re))
Module('Support for regular expressions (RE). \n\nThis module provides ...
```

Python 3:

```
>>> import ast, inspect
>>> ast.parse(inspect.getsource(re))
<_ast.Module at 0x7fdcbd1ac550>
```

Comment: In Python 3 the `compiler` module has been deprecated. Use `ast.parse` instead.

Comment: Also consider using `textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(re))` which will handle functions defined inside other functions or classes. (otherwise the extra leading whitespace will make the parser mad)

Comment: @pschanely your comment is why I actually came here

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to get an AST except from source code.  If you explain why you don't want to re-parse the source files, maybe we can help with that.

Comment: it just seemed unnecessary and unwieldy to me and i don't necessarily know the paths.

Comment: If you've imported a module m, then the file it came from is `m.__file__`.  It should be straightforward to re-read the source.  As The MYYN points out, `inspect` has methods that are helpful also.