# How can you list all return values for endpoints in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

In a Flask app, I'd like to list the return values for all endpoints.  For example I have a route like:

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    if current_user is None or current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.user', uuid=current_user.uuid))
```

I can list all routes with `app.url_map.iter_rules()`.  Now I'd like to also list all the return values like:

1. return `redirect(url_for('auth.login'))`
2. return `redirect(request.args.get('next')`
3. url_for `('main.user', uuid=current_user.uuid)`
4. and for example `return render_template("auth/change_password.html")`

This is different from extracting all html links from a rendered webpage, as a Flask endpoint could render different webpages, depending on the return value.

The end goal is to make a graph of all endpoints and redirects in a Flask application.  That would make mapping the user flow much easier.

Comment: Interesting question but sadly I don't think there is a way to do this. Python is a run time interpreted language so until a piece of code is encountered during run time it won't be executed. The workaround for this maybe to have good unit testing in place with ample code coverage.

Comment: I don't think that this is generally possible because there might be something like `return eval(userinput)`. You could though just analyze the sourcecode and just "grep" every route decorator and associate them with the returns.

Comment: @kiran I understand that solving this problem in all circumstances is equivalent to the halting problem.  In lisp you'd use a 'code walker' to extract and list all return values.

Comment: @syntonym  A solution which would return 'eval(userinput)' (and not evaluating that) would be good enough.

Comment: @unuseless It should be possible to analyze each endpoint via the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) (use [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812144/python-get-the-abstract-syntax-tree-of-imported-function) to get the sourcecode of the endpoint), look for return statements and print the lines in which they are (given by `AST.lineno`).